# Some examples of clean topological spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras

I asked  [this  question at  MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772552/some-examples-of-clean-topological-spaces)  but  I did  not received any answer, so I repeat it here at  MO:

What is  an example of  a Hausdorff topological space $X$, not a singleton,  such that the ring $C(X)$ of all real (or complex) valued continuous functions on $X$ is a **clean ring**?

A clean ring is  a ring in which every element is  a sum of a unit and an idempotent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the two point set will do. Also an infinite discrete set will do.
To give a less obvious example, let me argue that every compact space with a basis of clopen sets will do too.

Let $X$ be such and consider a real valued function $f$ on $X$.
Consider the compact subset $\{f \leq 1/3\}$ and cover it with clopen sets that are contained in $\{f<2/3\}$. Choose a finite subcover and let $p$ be the characteristic function of its union. This is a continuous idempotent. $u=f-p$ is a continuous function that is bounded away from 0, hence a unit. $f=p+u$.

Answer (score 12):

For a Tychonoff space $X$, the rings $C(X)$ and $C(X,\mathbb{C})$ are each clean if and only if the space $X$ is strongly zero-dimensional (s.z.d). This is a result of Azarpanah, me, and most recently Arora and Kundu.

A Tychonoff space $X$ is s.z.d if and only if every cozeroset is the countable union of clopen subsets. In particular, s.z.d implies a base of clopen sets. Examples of s.z.d spaces include the rationals, the Cantor space, and **W**.